# Windows phone 8.1 Mapcontrol disabling rotate

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, maps, bing-maps

Wondered if anyone could help on this. Developing a Windows phone 8.1 app with Visual Studio 2015 and trying to disable the rotate. I've currently "disabled" it using the heading changed event and resetting the heading back to 0. Current control looks like:

```
<Maps:MapControl Grid.Row="1"  Background="Black" Holding="MainMap_Holding" 
Heading="0" HeadingChanged="MainMap_HeadingChanged"
x:Name="MainMap" 
MapServiceToken="{StaticResource MapServiceTokenString}"
MapTapped="MainMap_MapTapped"
>
```

The issue with this method is it causes the map to just jump back which doesn't look the best.

I've tried using the 'ManipulationMode', however even setting ManipulationMode="None" does absolutely nothing and the map still functions as normal. I'd think the "proper" way to do this would have been using manipulation mode if it was working, however it seems not to be.

Any suggestions to stop map rotation would be greatly received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the RotateInteractiveMode option was introduced in the Windows 10 map control and not the WP8.1 map control. For WP8.1 you can do the following:

```
MyMap.HeadingChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    MyMap.Heading = 0;
};
```

Depending on the version of the map control you are using there may be a IsRotateGestureEnabled property.

Comment: Ended up using this method. As rbrundritt said RotateInteractiveMode option is not available on windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can disable the rotation from the XAML itself. Just add the following property to the map control, and keep it as disabled:

```
RotateInteractionMode="Disabled"
```

Now your code should look like:

```
<Maps:MapControl Grid.Row="1"
Background="Black"
Holding="MainMap_Holding" 
Heading="0"
HeadingChanged="MainMap_HeadingChanged"
RotateInteractionMode="Disabled"
x:Name="MainMap" 
MapServiceToken="{StaticResource MapServiceTokenString}"
MapTapped="MainMap_MapTapped"
>
```

Comment: As rbrundritt said RotateInteractiveMode option is not available on windows 8.1.